# How to set $http.error() in angular throughout all $http calls?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, error-handling

How would I go about setting a function for all .error calls from the $http service wherever used.

Throughout my app I have used many $http calls wrapped in a service and would like to avoid duplication of implementing all .error methods.

e.g.

```
postTest: function (data) {
        var url = '/test';
        return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: data
            }).
            success(function (data) {
                return data;
            }).
            error(function (status) {  //Avoid duplication of this throughout all $http calls.
                if (status === 404) {}
                return status;
            });
    }
```

Comment: One possible way is setting up your own [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) method.

Answer (score 0):

you could create and interceptor to catch all the errors

so something like this

```
var applicationWideInterceptors = function ($q, toastrSrvc) {
    return {
        responseError:function(rejection) {
            //do something with the rejection
            if (rejection.status === 404) {
                toastrSrvc.error(rejection.data);
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
};

app.factory("appWideIntercpt", ["$q", "toastrSrvc", applicationWideInterceptors]);
```

dont forget to add it to your config block

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push("appWideIntercpt"
```